# Future educators writing nonsense questions

Tags: primary-education, teacher-preparation

I teach future elementary educators mathematics content courses.

We play a lot in class with tasks like "Write a variety of word problems which would require the student to multiply 2.3 by 1.4".

Often the questions which students produce are unintelligible, unanswerable, or target the wrong operation.

Unintelligible:  "Bob has 2.3 pizza, and Jim has 1.4 pop.  How much all together?"

Unanswerable:  "I have 2.3 dollars, and want to buy 1.4 cups of ice cream.  How much more money do I need to buy the ice cream?"

Target the wrong operation: "I have 2.3 cups of flour and 1.4 cups of water.  If a recipe calls for 1 cup of each, how many recipes can I make?"  (The operation here is $\textrm{min}(2.3,1.4)$)

No matter how much we practice this, when the exam comes around I still have a very large percentage of students writing these kinds of responses.  This is extremely concerning to me, to the point that I don't feel comfortable with students who would produce such responses becoming educators.

Have others observed this phenomenon?  Is there any research on it?  Does anyone have success with fixing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried starting this kind of lesson with an assignment where you provide a large list of problems for students to organize into those (or other) types of error-types? I would think this could set the stage for further discussion when they write and submit their own problems.

Comment: @guest Do you think someone who can flawlessly calculate 2.4*1.3 by hand, but writes a question like the unintelligible one above, is going to be well equipped to teach? Would they even know when to use multiplication if it came up in their real life (say buying 1.3 pounds of beans from the bulk bin at a price of $2.40 per pound)?

Comment: @NickC I usually give such a problem to the class, collect anonymous responses, and then we discussions them and categorize them.  I encourage a respectful classroom, where we do not ridicule errors, and this is usually an enjoyable and (seemingly) productive class period.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112691/discussion-on-question-by-steven-gubkin-future-educators-writing-nonsense-questi).

Comment: Will the students drop out if they fail to improve?  This is, are you trying to help students pass by improving their skills, or are you on damage-control, trying to do what you can to improve their skills before they go to work?

Comment: Hypothesis: _the students are fully aware when they write these questions that the questions are unintelligible, unanswerable, and/or target the wrong operation, but the students are uncreative, and just can't generate anything better in the time available_.  Some of the approaches suggested in the answers will be able to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Do you observe the same issue when you give them whole numbers? Perhaps they understand multiplication with whole numbers, but they cannot think of questions with decimals, and the stress of trying to spontaneously generate questions involving decimals results in them finally just putting down a nonsensical question. Is there a time limit on this exercise?

Comment: @DanielHatton Perhaps you could craft an answer which addresses this interesting point.

Comment: @Joe These difficulties are less frequent, but still present, with whole number responses.  A few students will have the question "3 people all have 4 cookies, how many cookies do they have all together?" as their "main example" for multiplication of integers.  This doesn't work with decimals, but they will sometimes just try to replace the 3 with 2.3 and the 4 with 1.4.  This leads to another form of nonsense where they reference 2.3 people.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Nick C has already done that for me: following the proposal in the first paragraph of Nick C's answer will be a good way of testing my hypothesis.  If my hypothesis is right, many of the same students who write the nonsense questions will prove quite competent in the exercise proposed by Nick C; in that case, you can stop worrying so much about their basic comprehension and focus on helping develop their creativity instead.  (Of course, the experiment might go the other way as well, and confirm that you really _do_ need to worry about their basic comprehension.)

Comment: *Does anyone have success with fixing this problem ?* - Yes. Convert to the metric system.

Comment: @Lucian There is nothing in the question about units.  While a student could write a response to this question involving metric units ("how many square centimeters are in a 2.3 cm by 1.4 cm rectangle?" for instance), this is not needed.  Also, this same problem arises when asking for computations involving fractions, such as $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in the US?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You might try starting this kind of lesson with an assignment where you provide a list of different responses to the prompt "Write a variety of word problems which would require the student to multiply 2.3 by 1.4" and have students (perhaps in groups) arrange and rank them by clarity/mistakes/etc. Instead of having students start by writing their own word problems, by bringing your own list of good-and-bad examples, you're not setting students up to be ridiculed since you've created the set of responses.

I've had colleagues do this kind of thing with other tasks, such as *learning how to show work* in an intermediate algebra class. The first assignment is to take a stack of 8-10 teacher-created "solutions" to a word problem, read them with your group, and rank them by clarity and completeness. Then the class discussion revolves around lessons they can take from this when writing up their own solutions to word problems.

[Edit on 9/4]: I think another benefit of this plan is that if you follow up with a full-class discussion about why certain of the responses were objectionable, you'll likely build a class-specific vernacular that students may find light/playful to use when identifying errors in their/other's writing: Your "unintelligible" may be dubbed "what a mess" or "I can't even", etc. Since these descriptors aren't [standard](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17829/allowing-nonstandard-mathematical-language-and-or-notation) mathematical terms, I personally would readily accept new language if it means the class is learning the topic at hand and can communicate about it (though I would surely use my own terms from time to time in discussion).

Comment: Iteration that I've used for similar exercises: Instead of instructor writing their own problems, recycle a stack of answers from the last semester you asked this in-class (with names removed, of course). I find there's many dimensions of "bad" responses that I would have no hope of accurately recreating on my own.

Comment: This is probably the most helpful answer that could be written, but it still seems unrealistic to me. If someone is 20 years old and doesn't understand what multiplication is, then there is a vanishingly small chance that instruction in a college class will fix the problem. I have taught a teacher-prep class like this, and it was the worst experience I've had in 25 years of teaching. The students didn't want to be there and weren't willing to put in any effort outside of class. The underlying issue is the abysmally low academic level of the people who are in these programs.

Comment: Writing instructors do this and call it [norming](http://writing.umn.edu/tww/responding/norming.html).

Comment: @BenCrowell Do the student responses in the question necessarily imply their authors do not understand multiplication? I think it is not implausible the students understand multiplication just fine (in the sense that they can solve problems with it and apply it in their daily lives), but simply do not know how to write good questions (yet). Of course, there will be hopeless cases and if you already know that your students do not want to learn you might as well not bother, but if not I would prefer to make a reasonable attempt to improve my teaching before giving up on them.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, the way I get around the ridicule problem in my class is to ask each student to write a "good" question and a "bad" question, then pass them in anonymously.  As we are categorizing, we can discuss whether they were good or bad without implying that some people in the class were incapable of writing a good question.

Comment: @Discretelizard *""Bob has 2.3 pizza, and Jim has 1.4 pop. How much all together?"* is a question that shows that someone does not understand what multiplication is. They may be able to mechanically multiply but do not understand what this means. The same way as being able to press a button and know the light will go on does not mean that someone understands why this happens (beside the vague "electricity" thing)

Comment: @WoJ No, the question "Bob has 2.3 pizza, and Jim has 1.4 pop. How much all together?" shows that someone has their language skills frozen at 6-year old level, and should have never be given a high school diploma, much less admitted to college. It shows pitiful state of American elementary and secondary education, which starts with non-working Whole Language / Balanced Literacy programs, promoted by organizations like NCTE. When kids cannot read and write, they cannot learn other subjects. Forget about math or physics. 2.3 what? And 1.4 what? Kilograms and liters? You cannot even add them up.

Comment: @RustyCore: One should remember that a high school diploma is now essentially considered a right in the US.  Our disabilities laws say that everyone is entitled to a program of study achievable by them that leads to a high school diploma, so if a pupil has a severe intellectual disability (say an IQ of 30), their school district must devise a program of study achievable by people with that disability, and if the pupil finishes that program of study, they get a high school diploma.

Answer (score 26):

**Note: This is an answer from a non-US perspective, after reading some remarks from @Rusty Core I fear it won't be helpful.**

How about you set certain standards and let sub-standard students fail your class? Just like in every other course the goal is to separate the wheat from the chaff.

I wouldn't want my children to be educated by teachers asking the kind of exam questions you provided as examples. If they don't improve until the re-exam they fail the class.

*This is extremely concerning to me, to the point that I don't feel comfortable with students who would produce such responses becoming educators.*

Why concerning? Why are you so invested in these students, it's not your fault, that they don't study. Just fail them.

Comment: American elementary and secondary education is a political minefield that has little to do with education per se, and more with progressive — or conservative — ideas that the leaders of this, should I say, industry, want to push. Many great ideas have been tried in the last, let's say, 60 years, and failed. Many bad pedagogical, but nicely-sounding from progressives' perspective ideals have been applied since early 1920s and still hold their grip on the system. Want the best education for your kids? Homeschool them.

Comment: It is concerning to the OP, because his job at his institution is at stake. In the U.S. students can choose their prof, and if he fails bad students, no one will chose him. So he will be fired. Students are customers. Profs are providers of a service. Since the students pay seriously big money for their higher education, they expect result, not in the form of knowledge, but in the form of good grades and diploma. This is market economy in education to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is hilarious. How can such a system ever ensure quality teaching? Who in his right mind would allow students to just switch professors without reasons going beyond "his class is hard"? Maybe my answer is not a good answer in such a broken system then.

Comment: Your updated comment makes sense. It's still hilarious though. Higher education is not something you buy in a store. Humboldt would scratch his eyes out reading this. It's frightening how free-market radical America is even when it comes to education. Here in Germany there are state-regulated examinations ("Staatsexamen") prospective students need to pass in order to be able to teach pupils, no matter their age.

Comment: Homeschooling is forbidden here as well, which makes sense. Especially the young children should get education without home made political biases and every child should get the same level of education irrespective of their parents wealth or education.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum: I did not know that homeschooling was forbidden in Germany. Here in France, it is allowed and a tiny percentage (0.3% from what I read) do it. Out of these, there is probably a portion for children who cannot attend school for medical reasons so the actual number of these who do want to do it is negligible.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum as far as I know, even in Germany there is (or recently has been) a way to bypass "Staatsexamen" as a career-changer if one has a degree in a "most wanted" subject (such as math or most nat. sciences)... due to lack of qualified teachers in this area.

Comment: FWIW I don't think students choosing their professors is quite as much of an issue as Rusty's comment suggests. In my experience, university students have _some_ choice about which classes to take, and they can take into account who is leading the class when making that choice, but within a given class they don't generally get to choose who teaches them.

Comment: @DavidZ What do you mean? In any institution of substantial size, and in courses (such as, surely "math for elementary educators", or what have you) that are taken by many students, there will be multiple sections per semester, and students absolutely go to considerable effort to choose professors with whom they don't expect to fail. Such efforts are the reason websites like RateMyProfessors exist.

Comment: @KevinArlin Well, as I mentioned I can only speak from my own experience, but what I have seen with a number of large courses is that (1) it's not necessarily revealed who will be leading which section, and (2) the teachers go to considerable effort to apply uniform grading standards so that students can't significantly influence their chances of passing by choosing one section over another. I don't doubt that what you're talking about happens in some places, but it's definitely not _always_ the case.

Comment: I think more important than Rusty Core's claim is that in the U.S. educators are poorly paid and supported, there is no national standard or guidance, and for over 100 years education majors have been the lowest-qualified of all incoming college students, and especially weak in math. As noted in comments now in chat, we should have math specialists but don't. So the current state is a choice between poor teachers and none at all. https://web.archive.org/web/20150204031027/https://qz.com/334926/your-college-major-is-a-pretty-good-indication-of-how-smart-you-are/

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum I'd much rather have homemade political bias than state made brainwashing. Homemade political bias is localized, state-made propaganda kills millions and ruins the lives of more. German's should understand this especially.

Comment: Furthermore recommend you read the very interesting comments on the OP moved to chat, like this one from former-school-educator now-PhD student Opal E: "I had the same naive thoughts when I was graduating from my education program: That simply failing these students was the answer. But failing these students means that our elementary kids get long-term subs instead of permanent teachers due to the severe lack of people willing to even do the job in the first place."

Comment: "So the current state is a choice between poor teachers and none at all." Why is this not a huge election campaign theme in America? This is outrageous and would actually be quite easily solvable in 8 years. Push fo standardized final exams  for all aspiring teachers on a federal  or state level and pay competitive wages. This stage of education is crucial. Hard to comprehend that the people care so little. I'm guessing there are good teachers at the elementary schools in the more privileged areas...

Answer (score 11):

Partial answer regarding an **approach to fix this problem**.

First: Don't tell them (criticism), but lead them to find out themselves (insight). Now comes the fun part. *Don't let them write just the questions*.

1. Have them each write the **question** on one sheet, and write the correct **solution**, and a short (maybe single-sentence) **explanation** for their solution (choice of operation, solution method) on a different sheet.
2. Then have them swap just the question sheets and try to solve it :)

   If the question is intelligible, answerable, using the correct operations, *and* the other person is sufficiently competent, he or she should not only be able to give the correct solution, but also to come up with a very similar explanatory statement.

In case the other person *isn't* able to do that, you'll have demonstrated to them that *something* isn't working yet... with no criticism involved.

Comment: Of course, this requires the students to all have different prompts; if they all have "Write a variety of word problems which would require the student to multiply 2.3 by 1.4", then they'll have no difficulty "solving" each other's problems whether or not they're coherent.

Comment: I like this suggestion, and have in fact used it.  I always emerge from these experiences hopeful that something has been learned, but this understanding does not seem to persist through time.

Comment: @ruakh, even if they know what the answer is supposed to be, they should struggle to come up with a sensible explanatory statement to nonsensical questions. I wonder if doing even just the first part (having the question authors *also* write solutions) would reduce the number of nonsensical questions, when they realize that they cannot answer their own question.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin, it’s not surprising to me that the understanding doesn’t persist, for the reason given in the popular comment to the other answer by Ben Crowell. Your observations are making me believe we should have elementary MATH teachers, just like we have MATH teachers in higher grades, rather than having elementary education teachers try to teach all subjects. Of course, not to sound mean, but perhaps the students who gave the first two responses shouldn’t be teaching anything.

Answer (score 10):

You might start out by giving them a test in the kind of arithmetic they are supposed to teach. [This article](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2010/feb/14/primary-teachers-fail-maths-tests) in the Guardian from 2010 reported that many primary school teachers in the UK were unable to do the arithmetic required by the primary curriculum.

> Fewer than four out of 10 of those who sat the test – designed for 11-year-olds – could calculate 2.1% of 400, and only a third answered correctly that 1.4 divided by 0.1 was 14. Overall, four out of ten scored 40% or below, only one got all the answers correct and the average mark was 12 out of 27 or 45%.
>
> [...]
>
> The test, carried out for the Channel 4 documentary series Dispatches, included addition and multiplication sums, ­simple algebra and questions involving fractions, conversions and averages. ­Teachers performed well on some of the easier questions. For example, 97% were able to work out 2 x 5 - 4 = 6 and 75% knew that three sevenths of 21 was 9. But only six teachers (4%) knew that the answer to 2 divided by 0 was infinity.
>
> The test was set by Richard Dunne, a former teacher and the author of Maths Makes Sense.
>
> Dunne said teachers were "thoroughly dedicated", but argued the test showed that more than half of them understood "so little maths that they cannot be conveying mathematics to their children in the classroom".

(Aside: the question about infinity is maybe a little unfair, given that its not on the curriculum. But bright kids will be asking about it.)

The problem seems to be that the kind of person who becomes a primary school teacher is often not strong on maths and science; the job tends to attract people who are stronger on the nurturing and caring side, who can bring an understanding attitude to a shoe full of wee. Many of them haven't done any maths since scraping through GCSE (i.e. age 16), and what understanding they had then has only decayed in the intervening years. So being a bit confused about what the technical term "multiplication" means is only to be expected.

Comment: Actually, isn't the question about infinity given the _wrong_ answer?  Infinity isn't a number (at least, in any sense that pupils should be using), and the real answer is that 2 / 0 is _undefined_ — or, in loose terms, can't be done.  (Of course, in real numbers the result _approaches_ infinity as the denominator approaches 0 from above; but then it approaches _negative_ infinity if from below, so it's obvious that you can't infer one or the other for 2 / 0 itself.)  And even if infinity's not on the curriculum, shouldn't pupils know that ‘you can't divide by zero’?

Comment: There is actually an interesting conversation to be had about division by 0.  2/0 and 0/0 are undefined for different reasons. 2/0 is undefined because there is no number whose product with 0 is 2.  0/0 is undefined because every number has a product of 0 with 0! Discussing limits in an informal way is also intriguing.  Small children and future educators alike can become very animated when discussing these kinds of pathological situations.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is essentially correct. Most people trying to become teachers were taught math from teachers who didn't know math, so there's no reason to expect them to be competent. I find the reporting about the test interesting too. 12/27 is closer to 44%, and 2/0 is undefined (there's no reason to assume we're considering anything other than the reals, and I see no reason to give the test maker the benefit of the doubt about even knowing about number systems where it is defined)

Comment: I agree with this - you have to teach them to solve the problems (and understand them) before they can write new ones. The question seems to be asking how to shortcut this, which seems fruitless.

Comment: There are also many example in the both the U.S. and Canada over the years of this same thing. Not sure if that would add to the answer, but could dig some up if desired.

Comment: @Thierry: Re: "12/27 is closer to 44% [than to 45%]": Presumably the average was not *exactly* 12, but rather, just some value in [11.5, 12.5). Any value in [12.015, 12.285) would give a percentage in [44.5%, 45.5%).